# PHP Shell_Exec do not execute .sh file via cronjob

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, cron

I made a php in my www page that generates a .txt file depending on what button is pressed on the webpage. The .txt has full path to the shell I want to run. I have a cronjob that runs every minutes that reads the command. Here is the php file that the cronjob executes:

```
  <?php
  define("CRONFILENAME", "SERVERCOMMAND.txt"); //Will put what the conr job needs to do in there    -- Will always go into the CronJobs DIrectory
  define("SERVERBINPATH", "/home/myuser/server_v2/bin/"); // This is the   path of the java bon server
  define("WEBLINKTOCRON", "http://localhost/CronJobs/");
  define("PATHTOWWW", "/var/www/html/CronJobs/");

  $filename = WEBLINKTOCRON . CRONFILENAME;

  if ($filename != "") { //If the file exist read it and then delete it
    $removeFileLog = exec("rm " . PATHTOWWW . "LastServerQuery.log");
    $file = file_get_contents("$filename");
    $removeFile = exec("rm " . PATHTOWWW . CRONFILENAME);
    $ServerQuery = "Executed Query at: " . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "\n";
    $ServerQuery = $ServerQuery . shell_exec("$file");
    file_put_contents(PATHTOWWW . "LastServerQuery.log", $ServerQuery);
  }

  ?>
```

The returned file (LastServerQuery.log) has the output of the server .sh and it shows correct information (as server started) But the server is never started.

The cronjob is started as sudo crontab -e (So it stats as root user)
I tried adding sh in front the the file so it looks like $ServerQuery = $ServerQuery . shell_exec("sh $file"); but doing so the returned LastServerQuery.log file is empty

Also I notice that when I run the cronjob.php (and by adding a file command in the www directory) I need to do CTRL+C to be able to get back my prompt line.

Thanks

EDIT: I was asked to provide the cron line: Here it is
*/1   *    *    *    *    php /home/myuser/server_v2/bin/cronjobs.php
I know the cronjob get executed and so is the php as the files gets deleted and edited. Also this is the sudo crontab -e. So my limited knowledge tells me that it is running as sudo.

Comment: this seems rather convoluted

Comment: Add your cronjob line to your question.